# NullPointer when trying to get ContentInfo from VFS FileObject

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

I'm successfully using VFS to download files from HTTP, SFTP, FTP, etc. I need to get the content type of the file and I've run into a strange thing that I'm not sure why is happening.

```
FileObject file = vfs.resolveFile(uri) ;
FileContent content = remote.getContent();

InputStream source = content.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
copy(source, target);

content.getSize(); // HACK: Prevents null-pointer in next line
String type = content.getContentInfo().getContentType();
```

If I remove the call to `getSize`, `content.getContentInfo` will return null. Why is this? Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you throw this line before and after the `getSize` call? `System.out.println(content.isOpen() ? "Open" : "Closed");`

Comment: What kind of file causes this error?

Comment: Looks like an [`issue`](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-issues/201207.mbox/%3C1860309366.38128.1342042175019.JavaMail.jiratomcat@issues-vm%3E)

Comment: @durron597 Will have to test that tomorrow at work.

Comment: @AdamArold Think I tried with HTML, XML and PDF over HTTP. Might have tried over SFTP as well, can recheck at work.

Comment: @SamRad It does indeed...

Comment: It seems that `getSize` has some side effect which is unhealthy for your app. In that case the problem is with the library.

Comment: @durron597 Tested now, and it reports 'Closed' both before and after the getSize call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam-Rad wrote, it is fixed in trunk (upcoming VFS 2.1):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-427